# How to add ng-model to Symfony form type checkboxes

Tags: angularjs, symfony

I have a few checkboxes in a symfony form like

```
->add('countries', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => 'Catalog:Countries',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true
        ])
```

how can I add ng-model to each checkbox to bind them to my angularJS script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here

[choice_attr](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-attr)

however, if some of the checkboxes are selected then you will loose this information on page load

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `attr` option for the parent `<select>` element or `choice_attr` option for the child `<option>` elements.

Example:

```
$builder->add('countries', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => 'Catalog:Countries',
    'choice_label' => 'name',
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => true,
    'attr' => [
      '[ng-model]' => 'countries'
    ],
    'choice_attr' => [
       '[selected]' => 'isCountrySelected()'
    ]
]);
```